# All page links in website to open chat window

Tags: javascript, html, href

I have a client that wants all his pages links in html home website , i.e. when click on any menu, home page, everything, to open chat support box. Normal href should be like this sample to do that but there are a few dozens of links on homepage and he doesn't want to manually remove each link but only to do it with a single code, this way he can simply remove it anytime.

```
<a href="javascript:jivo_api.open();">Open the chat</a>
```

Example of link I need to open chat when click on it:

```
<li class="list-link"> <a href="tyres/index.html"> <i class="tyres ico"></i> anvelope <i class="wlf wlf-arrow-right arrow-link"></i> </a> </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

> *Normal href should be like this sample*

The code you're showing is not using normal `href`s. It's using techniques that are 25+ years old and was the way we handled clicks before we had any API standards or were concerned with accessibility.

First, don't use hyperlinks solely  as JavaScript event hooks. Any visible element on a web page supports a `click` event, but hyperlinks denote navigation. Those who rely on assistive technologies, like screen readers, can have problems navigating your site when you use hyperlinks, but not for navigation. Instead, just use another inline element (like `span`) and give that your `click` event handler.

Second, `javascript:....` won't be needed because you'll be doing your JavaScript separate from your HTML (a.k.a. "Separation of Concerns").

Now, to your question. If you simply give any/all elements that should open a chat window when clicked a common CSS class, you can then create very simple code that will find all of them, loop over them, and assign them all the same event handler, which will open the chat.  Here's an example:

```js
// Get all the elements that have the "chat" class and put into an array
let chatElements = Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll(".chat"));

// Loop over the array
chatElements.forEach(function(item){
  // Assign an event handler
  item.addEventListener("click", function(){
    console.log("open chat window here");
  });
});
```

```css
.chat { cursor:pointer; color:blue; }
```

```html
<p class="chat">I will open the chat</p>
<p>I won't open the chat</p>
<div>I will <span class="chat">open the chat</span></div>
<h1 class="chat">I will open the chat</h1>
<h5>I won't open the chat</h5>
```

Comment: "a common CSS class" — Those are HTML classes. CSS has class selectors, not classes.

Comment: @Quentin Point taken about visible elements and their ability to be focused. As for your second comment, if you look at my code, you will see that I am using CSS, but that's really besides the point. You are confusing the HTML class *attribute*  with the *value* of that attribute, which is a CSS *class*.

Comment: I'm not. The value of the HTML class attribute is a list of HTML classes. CSS has class selectors. JavaScript has `getElementByClassName`. They reference HTML classes.

Comment: @Quentin While I take your point, I would just say that calling `.something` a CSS class is certainly a correct term - you're splitting hairs here.

Comment: I'm not talking about class selectors in CSS though, so that's irrelevant to my point.

Comment: But I am, and since you are commenting on my post, I think that makes it relevant since my code does have a CSS class (which you want to split hairs over and call a class selector).

Comment: You're arguing against a strawman. I was critising this sentence: "If you simply give any/all elements that should open a chat window when clicked a common CSS class, you can then create very simple code that will find all of them"

Comment: Also the question is about temporarily changing the functionality of existing links, so rewriting all the markup doesn't really address the problem being asked about. In fact, the question explicitly wants to avoid editing each link in the HTML.

Comment: On your last point, we agree. My answer is meant to inform the OP that his approach is misguided and suggests an alternate route.

Comment: The thing is that there are dozens of links, added class to each one is taking time while I need a simple code line to be added and removed when not need it anymore. I have updated the post with some sample link.

Comment: I understand. In my opinion, using an out-of-date solution that is not accessible and uses the languages incorrectly isn't appropriate even if that's what the client is currently using. You are free to ignore my post and down vote it if you like. But, if it were my client, I'd explain why their current code is wrong and bad and that I wasn't willing to take bad code and make it worse. Updating the code to use modern, standards-based approaches (even with dozens of links) would take about .5 hour since .html files are just text and you could easily open up the files and do a search & replace.

Answer (score -2):

```
$(function(){
     $('a').click(function(event) {
          event.preventDefault();   
         jivo_api.open();
     });
});
```

Comment: Please read [How to answer a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Also, the question was not tagged with JQuery.

Comment: That solution solved my problem ! I simply loaded JQuery lib and works perfectly !

Comment: This may have "worked", but it is completely inappropriate to use a link like this.